# C - int not-equal to printf?

Tags: c, pycparser

What this C statement does?

```
i=!({ printf("%d\n",r); });
```

*i* and *r* are integers.

I'm trying to parse it using pycparser which doesn't recognize it and raises an error:

> pycparser.plyparser.ParseError: :7:6: before: {

Thanks

Comment: This is not valid in standard C.

Comment: Get rid of the inner semi-colon.

Comment: this is a GNU statement expression extension.

Comment: int  r initialized to what? This is undefined behaviour.

Comment: this is __not__ not-equal-to, rather a unary negation and assignment.

Comment: I suppose this question has been asked to him in some exam for testing his syntactical knowledge

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I will go threw it tommorow

@AliAkberFaiz - it's not a question in exam, I'm working on code-data from a coding competition. this is one of the (accepted, somehow) submissions

Comment: Oh so you mean to say you will throw it tomorrow ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not standard C, but a GCC [statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) extension, which allows putting blocks in expressions and returns the value of the last statement in the block.

Because the block here has only one statement which is itself an expression, this is equivalent to:

```
i = !printf("%d\n",r);
```

This sets `i` to 1 if `printf` returned 0 (i.e. it succeeded but didn't print any characters), or 0 otherwise. Since this `printf` will always print at least two characters when it succeeds, `i` will always be 0.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like it is using a [GNU C extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) that allows to write a block statement where an expression is expected. The value of the block statement is the value of the last expression of the block.

For example:

```
int x = ({ int a = 1; a+2; });
```

will initialize `x` with `3`.

In your particular case the extension does not look very useful, because:

```
i=!({ printf("%d\n",r); });
```

is identical to:

```
i=!printf("%d\n",r);
```

I'm guessing that your original code is probably generated by some dark magic macro.

BTW, this code does not make much sense. It looks like it wants to check whether `printf` failed or suceeded in writing the text. But according to the specification, `printf` will return the number of bytes written if success or a negative value if error. So it will return 0 only if it writes 0 chars, and that will not happen with a `\n` at the end, and `i` will always end up being `0`, either with or without error.